# Getting TLS errors using AWS EMR to connect to MongoDB

Tags: ssl, amazon-emr

I am adding the certificates to the cluster via a bootstrap using keytool

```
keytool -import -file impl-stable.crt -alias impl-stable.crt -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

I have dumped the same cert from the key store and verified that it contains the SAN name that Spark is complaining about. Please note it *does* have the appropriate SAN names.

```
keytool -list -rfc -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias certs/impl-stable.crt
cut the PEM formatted cert out of the output from a.
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: critical
        DNS:mongodb-0, DNS:mongodb-0.mongodb-svc.core.svc.cluster.local, DNS:mongodb-1, DNS:mongodb-1.mongodb-svc.core.svc.cluster.local, DNS:mongodb-2, DNS:mongodb-2.mongodb-svc.core.svc.cluster.local, DNS:DNS:dev-canary-v4-mongodb0.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org, DNS:DNS:test-canary-v4-mongodb0.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org, DNS:DNS:impl-stable-v4-mongodb0.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org, DNS:DNS:impl-stable-v4-mongodb1.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org, DNS:DNS:impl-stable-v4-mongodb2.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org
  Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

The error:

```
"errorMessage": "com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@508e2f4c. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=impl-stable-v4-mongodb2.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org:30019, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching impl-stable-v4-mongodb2.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org found.}, caused by {java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching impl-stable-v4-mongodb2.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org found.}}, {address=impl-stable-v4-mongodb0.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org:30017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching impl-stable-v4-mongodb0.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org found.}, caused by {java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching impl-stable-v4-mongodb0.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org found.}}, {address=impl-stable-v4-mongodb1.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org:30018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching impl-stable-v4-mongodb1.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org found.}, caused by {java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching impl-stable-v4-mongodb1.ams-np-v4.internal.stuff.org found.}}]\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:403)
```

Answer (score 0):

We created the SAN with "DNS:" as part of the name...that explains things. Removing it and only using the FQDN seems to have resolved the issue.